# Validation in WCF Service with custom error message

Tags: validation, wcf, data-annotations

I am having a Data Contract as below. I want to return a custom error message if Name is empty. How can i achieve that?
Contract:

```
[DataContract]
    public class Employee
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Response:
ErrorCode: 111
ErrorDesc: null
ErrorText: null
StateCode: null

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is look at Fault Contracts,

A few links can be found on the net

1. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/788083/how-to-implement-fault-contract-in-wcf/
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/fault-contract
3. http://www.topwcftutorials.net/2014/07/wcf-fault-contract.html

But if that is a bit too much for what you want to achieve, you can look at [DataAnnotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations?view=netframework-4.7.2), putting

```
[DataMember]
[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Should be all that is required to force the user to create a value for

> Name

Also note that there is an overload to the [Required] Attribute that uses a custom error message

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="You have not supplied a value for the Name parameter")]
```

You can also combine this with

```
[StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "The Name value cannot exceed 20 characters. ")]
```

This would not look like

```
[DataContract]
    public class Employee
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
[StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "The Name value cannot exceed 20 characters. ")]
[Required(ErrorMessage="You have not supplied a value for the Name parameter")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```